# Efficient way to determine whether query will return "too many records" in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, search, forms, count

I've got a search form that could potentially return thousands of records; I'd like to show a message if the query returns more than 500 or so and make the user refine the search to get fewer results.

Am I stuck with doing a Select Count before running the actual query? What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the first 501 records. You can then display them and tell the user that they should refine their search.

[Here's how](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417081325/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070605-1.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
       SELECT TOP 500 *
       FROM   mytable
       )
```

This is more efficient than just `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

Would you also like to show your user the first n results? This can be achieved by writing "Select top n" (n being the maximum number of rows you want to get) instead of "Select". See [this link](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/Coffeehouse/102407-SQL-Server-and-LIMIT-clauses-on-SELECT-statements/) for more details.